# Override TextChanged event for a custom control not working

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, overriding

I tried this code in my custom user control in a C# Windows application:

```
public partial class HtextBox : DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit
{
    protected override void OnTextChanged(KeyEventArgs kpe)
    {
        if (kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D1 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D2 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D3 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D4 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D5 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D6 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D7 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D8 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D9 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D0
            ) {
                base.Text += kpe.KeyValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> Error 1  'myproject.HtextBox.OnTextChanged(object, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override  E:\my project\myproject\HtextBox.cs

I want create a custom textbox. Here I want this textbox just to get numbers as input. What would an example be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `KeyEventArgs` is a subclass of `System.EventArgs`, C# does not let you override a method with a subclass parameter. You need to override the method with the [signature from the base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged.aspx), and then cast to `KeyEventArgs` inside your function:

```
protected override void OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs args) {
    KeyEventArgs kpe = (KeyEventArgs)args;
    ...
}
```

**Edit:**
Since `OnTextChanged` does not provide `KeyEventArgs` and it looks like you need them, try overriding a different method:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs kpe) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: run time error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs'.

Comment: @hamze I'm not sure what's the exact type of args passed to `OnTextChanged`. Can you add a long output of `args.GetType()` or stop in the debugger and see what it is?

Comment: In Visual Studio (Express versions included) clicking F12 would take you to a definition. SO if you type inside an overriden funcion base.OnTextChanged() and then put the cursor in the middle of that word and click F12, it should take you to the base class's method definition.

Comment: But again, while this is a correct answer, probably you do not want to override the method! It will not behave the same way as an event handler, at the very least make sure to call base class implementation.

Comment: @hamze Oh yes, I have completely forgotten about calling the base class `OnTextChanged` after doing whatever you are planning to do! Thanks zmilojko!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, i get the point. but can you complete the answer i still got that error!

Comment: @hamze I do not have a copy of `DevExpress`, so I have no idea what is the exact subclass of `EventArgs` that they pass into `OnTextChanged`. Can you put a breakpoint on the `KeyEventArgs kpe = (KeyEventArgs)args;` line, inspect the `args` variable, and post its type? The idea is to cast `args` to that type instead of `KeyEventArgs`.

Comment: @hamze It does not look like you can get `KeyEventArgs` inside `OnTextChanged` method: according to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx), these arguments are passed to `OnKeyUp` and `OnKeyDown`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, i use this line : "KeyEventArgs kpe = e as KeyEventArgs;" and it works but kpe is null ! the type is : "System.Type{System.RuntimeType}"

Comment: thanks i do this and it works: this.KeyUp +=new KeyEventHandler(HtextBox_KeyUp);

Comment: @hamze Your `HtextBox_KeyUp` method should have this signature: `void HtextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs kpe)`

Answer (score 0):

@dasblinkenlight has given the correct answer to your question.

However, method `Form.OnTextChanged` is an event raising method, and should hardly ever be overridden. You might want to create an event handler, possibly in your derived class constructor:

```
this.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnTextChanged);
```

BTW, in Visual Studio, pressing the tab key once you have typed `+=` would generate an event handler for you.

Comment: i have this error now :  Error 1 Cannot assign to 'OnTextChanged' because it is a 'method group' E:\my project\HtextBox.cs

Comment: Sorry, my bad. THe method name is TextChanged, and the automatically generated event handler name is OnTextChanged (you can actually use any name you like). I have edited my answer to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot the first parameter in your event handler.

Change it to this:

```
protected override void OnTextChanged(Object sender, KeyEventArgs kpe) 
    {
        if (kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D1 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D2 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D3 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D4 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D5 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D6 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D7 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D8 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D9 ||
            kpe.KeyCode == Keys.D0
            ) {
                base.Text += kpe.KeyValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok, but i got this error now:   Error 1 'myproject.HtextBox.OnTextChanged(object, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override E:\my project\myproject\HtextBox.cs

Answer (score 0):

Simple code for input number only and support Delete and BackSpace keys.

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (numberMode)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Delete) { }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```